# What algorithm can be used for packing of regular shapes on the A1 sized sheet in optimal manner

Tags: java

What algorithm can be used for packing of regular shapes on the A1 sized sheet in optimal manner?

[image]

Comment: you may use some greedy heuristics, optimal way is NP-complete

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean packing of *irregular* shapes (as shown in the image), an optimal algorithm almost completely unfeasible.  However, efficient approximations do exist.  There are infinitely many non-trivial solutions to this problem, and unfortunately I'm not aware of any way to find the optimal solution.

I need to point out that this is very different from the well-studied rectangle packing problem (which is certainly solvable), as the sides of the irregular shapes rarely align flush, and rotation must also be considered.

The best approximations involve greedily packing the shapes one-by-one starting with the largest, and ending with the smallest, moving each shape as far to the bottom left as possible before adding to the next shape to the canvas.

This paper describes a few algorithms that *approximate* solutions to this problem:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/84b0/6942a8986c6214fc88c000265c7fe7f78f52.pdf

You might also be interested in methods to solve the simpler rectangle packing problem:
https://codeincomplete.com/posts/bin-packing/

As your question is tagged Java, you can use the Area class to easily check irregular intersections.